# Android Cleanup/Content Views

Tags: android

I have a quick question about content views. Once I load a new one, is the previous one disposed of? Does it keep running? is it tabbed? How can I close out of it? I have a program that goes from main screen > to screen one > screen two > final screen > back to main screen. Screens one, two and the final screen shouldn't be able to be backtraced after the final screen is met. All these views are also loaded from one class separate from the main, if that means anything (I'm beginner in android, I don't know much about any of this).

Comment: It did! I marked it correct but I can't upvote it because I don't have enough rep, I'm sorry :(

Comment: Oh didnt see it thought you could do both of them

Comment: my answer wasn't the correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in Final Screen use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

to switch to MainScreen and remove all intermediate screens form the back stack.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do it using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` | `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in your `screen two` as follows :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ScreenTwo.this, FinalScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the layout by calling setContentView() repeatedly from one Activity, you are doing it wrong. The old references aren't retained.
One way is to have a separate Activity for each screen. If you don't want to be able to return to the current Activity, call `finish()` right after `startActivity(intent)`